# Getting Undefined is not a function in one of the function

Tags: react-native

I am very new to React Native. I am trying to make autocomplete text box in React Native. I am using react-native-autocomplete-input plugin. I am reading the data from JSON file. I keep getting this error. user is entering the service name in the text box so they can enter ser and it will show service1 as an option for user to select.

[image]

Below is my App.js code:

```
 /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */



import service from './services.json';


import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from 'react-native';



class Autocomp extends Component {
  static renderServices(coservice) {
    const { ser, Location, secondLoc} = coservice;


    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>{ser}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.openingText}>{secondLoc}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       query: '',
       services:[]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
      const {results: services} = service;
      this.setState({services});

  }

  findServices(query) {
    if (query === '') {
      return [];
    }

    const {services } = this.state;
    const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
    return services.filter(coservice=> coservice.ser.search(regex) >= 0);
  }

  render() {
    const { query } = this.state;
    const services = this.findservices(query);
    const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={services.length === 1 && comp(query, services[0].ser) ? [] : services}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
          placeholder="Enter Services here"
          renderItem={({ ser, Phone }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: ser })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {ser} 
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
        <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
          {services.length > 0 ? (
            Autocomp.renderServices(services[0])
          ) : (
            <Text style={styles.infoText}>
              Enter services
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 25
  },
  autocompleteContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    left: 0,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1
  },
  itemText: {
    fontSize: 15,
    margin: 2
  },
  descriptionContainer: {
    // `backgroundColor` needs to be set otherwise the
    // autocomplete input will disappear on text input.
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    marginTop: 25
  },
  infoText: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  directorText: {
    color: 'grey',
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 10,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  openingText: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});

export default Autocomp;
```

below is my JSON (services.json) file:

```
  {
    "id":1,
    "ser": "Service1",
    "Location": "TestLoc1",
    "Phone":"(999)-921-9292",
    "SecondLoc": "TestLoc",
    "email":"accrmail@asrclkrec.com",
    "sourceLat":"33.977806",
    "sourceLong":"-117.373261",
    "destLatL1":"33.613355",
    "destLongL1":"-114.596569",
    "destLatL2":"33.761693",
    "destLongL2":"-116.971169",
    "destAddr1": "Test Drive, 99999",
    "destAddr2": "Test City, Test Drive, 92345"
  },

  {
    "id":1,
    "ser": "TestService",
    "Location": "TestLoc1",
    "Phone":"(999)-921-9292",
    "SecondLoc": "TestLoc",
    "email":"accrmail@asrclkrec.com",
    "sourceLat":"33.977806",
    "sourceLong":"-117.373261",
    "destLatL1":"33.613355",
    "destLongL1":"-114.596569",
    "destLatL2":"33.761693",
    "destLongL2":"-116.971169",
    "destAddr1": "Test Drive, 99999",
    "destAddr2": "Test City, Test Drive, 92345"
  },
  ]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a silly mistake, your function names don't match. You called `findservices`, but it should be `findServices`, with an uppercase `S`

Also, I want to point out that your way of finding suggestions is fine, but there's a bug in it. In your `findServices` function, you have

```
const regex = new RegExp(`${query.trim()}`, 'i');
```

You're constructing a new regular expression from `query`, but this doesn't always succeed. For example, if user enters a special character such as `[`, then this line of code will throw an error, because `query` now contains an open bracket but not a closing bracket `]`, therefore, a regex cannot be constructed from `query`. You should change it to something like this:

```
findServices(query) {
    const inputValue = query.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;

    const { services } = this.state;
    return inputLength === 0 ? [] : services.filter(ser =>
        ser.toLowerCase().slice(0, inputLength) === inputValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition of K.Wu answer, please remove this line `const services = this.findservices(query);` in render method and placed it inside onChangeText of autocomplete . It should be triggered after user has typing the text on autocomplete box not rendered by default

```
Autocomplete
          autoCapitalize="none"
          autoCorrect={false}
          containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
          data={services.length === 1 && comp(query, services[0].ser) ? [] : services}
          defaultValue={query}
          onChangeText={text => this.findServices(text}
          placeholder="Enter Services here"
          renderItem={({ ser, Phone }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: ser })}>
              <Text style={styles.itemText}>
                {ser} 
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )}
        />
```

Comment: As soon as I removed the const services = this.findservices(query); I m getting the error saying "can't find variable services